# RPI 4B - Bluetooth unavailable on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, ubuntu

I want to use Bluetooth on a **Raspberry Pi 4B** which has Bluetooth included.

I used an **Ubuntu 20.04** 64-bit server image (using the *Imager*) mostly because I already know this OS.
After a fresh install, SSH connection, installation of `bluez`, it can't find the device. The following commands returned nothing:

```sh
$ hcitool dev
Devices:

$ hciconfig -a
```

I just reinstalled a **Raspberry Pi OS** 32-bit Lite (still with the *Imager*) on the micro-SD and without installing anything it works. Here is the output:

```sh
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    DC:A6:32:86:B6:5F

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
    BD Address: DC:A6:32:86:B6:5F  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:1500 acl:0 sco:0 events:88 errors:0
    TX bytes:2956 acl:0 sco:0 commands:88 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'raspberrypi'
    Class: 0x000000
    Service Classes: Unspecified
    Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
    HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x13b
    LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x6119
    Manufacturer: Cypress Semiconductor Corporation (305)
```

What is missing on my Ubuntu ? Is it able to use the BT device ?

Comment: Don't ask us - ask Canonical. They insist on using their own kernel and firmware.

Comment: I hesitated about asking on AskUbuntu but I thought this maybe was something more related about RPIs...

Comment: Driver in kernel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally solved it !
I thought this was an issue and searched how to *"fix"* it but it is an intended behaviour.

**20.04 solution ([source [FR]](https://www.framboise314.fr/gerer-le-bluetooth-avec-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-sur-raspberry-pi-4/)):**

Install the `pi-bluetooth` package:

```sh
sudo apt-get install pi-bluetooth
```

Edit the `/boot/firmware/usrcfg.txt` file to add the following line at the end:

```
include btcfg.txt
```

Reboot:

```sh
sudo reboot
```

Check that the device is detected:

```sh
hciconfig -a

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
    ...
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo done ! Went away before I could accept my answer.

Comment: maybe the file /boot/firmware/usrcfg.txt should be /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop (Raspberry Pi Imager version), this is how I got it working:

From a terminal, `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

When that's all done (and it will take a while), run this:

`sudo apt install bluetooth pi-bluetooth bluez blueman`

Some of those might already be installed, it's ok just let it do it's thing... next, REBOOT

After you log back in from the reboot, you will see a little bluetooth icon at the upper right of your screen. Click on it and add your Bluetooth devices in there (blueman is the name of that app).

Answer (score 1):

On 22.04 you might need to do an additional step to installing `pi-bluetooth`.  Disable the serial uart that interferes with the bluetooth interface.
Edit `/boot/firmware/config.txt` and set `enable_uart=0` or run `sudo pibootctl set serial.enabled=off`

For some reason 22.04 removes the `btcmd.txt` that's included in other distributions, so make sure your `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` includes the following settings: `net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc`